# MSDAORA provider not found for asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, oracle, database-connection, oledb

I've got stuck with strange Oracle connection error on Windows Server 2003 x64 (IIS 6)

While console .Net application that runs onbehalf of administrator successfully connects to Oracle 10g Express via OleDb [Connection string looks like: `Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=server-ip:port;User Id=user;Password=password;`]

ASP.NET 4.0 web-site (application pool runs on behalf of administrator too) fails with error:
The 'MSDAORA' provider is not registered on the local machine

Connection string is the same, but it doesn't work for asp.net site. What shall I check?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Social.MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/a637b3b2-e570-4435-b8f2-0aaa642d0e3a/) link seems to point to the fact that you have x86 drivers installed;

From my viewpoint you have two options:

1. Convert the app to run on 32bit mode in IIS - Can help if you require assistance. [LINK](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2005/04/aspnet-32-bit-on-windows-server-x64.html)
2. Download and try the 64bit version of the drivers. [Oracle x64 downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to [enable 32-bit applications](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true) for the IIS Application Pool your application is using. I would suggest [creating a new application pool](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e0963d53-3361-498e-8b34-50b69646f48d.mspx?mfr=true) specifically for your application making sure to enable 32-bit applications.

You'll likely suffer performance issues but at least you'll be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue in one of my applications with ASP(MSDAORA connection) - oracle environment with following fix from 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784046.aspx

following are the steps

To enable IIS 6.0 to run 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows
1.Open a command prompt and navigate to the %systemdrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts directory.

2.Type the following command:

cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 true

3.Press ENTER.